# Creating tables with consecutive number via method

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to build a GPS database in which each table represents one trip.
For this it is necessary to create a new table by pressing a button.

So far I've done everything.

But I want the tables to be displayed according to this pattern:
Trip_1; Trip_2; Trip_3 ...

But I always get the error message that the table name is null.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Trip_ (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Table TEXT)
```

Please help me to find my mistake.

This is my database class:

```
public class GPSDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

String TAG = "GPSDatabase";

int tnumber = 0;


public static GPSDatabase INSTANCE = null;

private static final String DB_NAME              = "eelo";
private static final int    VERSION              = 1;
public  static       String TABLE_NAME           = "Trip_0";
public  static final String TABLE_TRIP           = "Trip_";

public  static final String TABLE_COLUMN         = "Table";

public  static final String ID_COLUMN            = "ID";
public  static final String NUMBER_COLUMN        = "Number";
public  static final String DISTANCE_COLUMN      = "Distance";
public  static final String LATITUDE_COLUMN      = "Latitude";
public  static final String LONGITUDE_COLUMN     = "Longitude";


private GPSDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}


public static GPSDatabase getInstance (final Context context){
    if (INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = new GPSDatabase(context);
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String createTripQuery =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRIP + " (" + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + TABLE_COLUMN + " TEXT)";

    String createQuery;
    if (tnumber==0) {
        createQuery =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + NUMBER_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " + DISTANCE_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " + LATITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL, " + LONGITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL)";
    }
    else{
        createQuery =
                "CREATE TABLE " + getTrip(tnumber) + " (" + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + NUMBER_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " + DISTANCE_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " + LATITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL, " + LONGITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL)";
    }
    db.execSQL(createTripQuery);
    db.execSQL(createQuery);
    Log.d(TAG, "Table created");
    tnumber++;

}
```

Here I get the Tablename of the new Trip:

```
public String getTrip(final long id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TRIP, new String[]{ID_COLUMN, TABLE_COLUMN}, ID_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);

    String table = null;

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        table = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_COLUMN));

    }

    Log.d(TAG, "getTable: "+table);
    return table;
}
```

And here is the ONCLICK-Methode from Main Activity;

```
public static GPSDatabase db;
public static int tripNumber = 0;
public static boolean clicked=false;
int NAV = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

    db = GPSDatabase.getInstance(this);

...

    Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("new Trip ","clicked");
            tripNumber++;

            long newID = -1;

            try{
                SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(db.TABLE_COLUMN, "Trip_"+tripNumber);

                newID = database.insert(db.TABLE_TRIP, null, values);

            }catch (SQLiteException e){
                Log.e(TAG,"insert");
            }finally {
                Log.d(TAG,"TableTrip insert with ID " + newID);
            }

            SQLiteDatabase db1;
            db1 = db.getWritableDatabase();
            db.TABLE_NAME = db.TABLE_TRIP+tripNumber;
            String dropTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + (db.TABLE_NAME+(tripNumber-1));
            db1.execSQL(dropTable);
            String createQuery =
                    "CREATE TABLE " + db.TABLE_NAME + " (" + db.ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + db.NUMBER_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " + db.DISTANCE_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " + db.LATITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL, " + db.LONGITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL)";


            db1.execSQL(createQuery);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `table` is a keyword that cannot be used as a column name. That's the syntax issue. A bigger issue is that you really should not be modelling your data like that - don't create new tables dynamically, instead keep the table schema fixed and put the variable part such as trip ids in as data.

Comment: ok thank you I remodeled it

Comment: @TominB actually you can have **table** as a column name if you really want. You can enclose it in single quotes, double quotes, square brackets or graves. as per [SQLite Keywords](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with naming the column as **Table** in `public  static final String TABLE_COLUMN         = "Table";`
. SQLite assumes that it has come across the keyword TABLE which would syntactically be wrong.

If you really wanted a column named Table, this is possible, you could use `public  static final String TABLE_COLUMN         = "'Table'";`
. However, this could still be problematic and confusing.

You could also use `_yourcolumnname` to avoid using the recommended (but relatively seldom used)

> SQLite adds new keywords from time to time when it takes on new
>   features. So to prevent your code from being broken by future
>   enhancements, **you should normally quote any identifier that is an
>   English language word**, even if you do not have to.[emphasis added]

More info at [SQLite Keywords](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

So perhaps `public  static final String TABLE_COLUMN         = "_Table";`

However, perhaps the better solution would be to apply normalisation (reduction of database redundancy) and have a single table with a column, that identifies the **trip**, rather than having multiple structurally identical tables.

e.g. you could use :-

```
private static final String DB_NAME              = "eelo";
private static final int    VERSION              = 1;
public  static final String TABLE_TRIP           = "Trip_";

public  static final String ID_COLUMN            = "ID";
public  static final String NUMBER_COLUMN        = "Number";
public  static final String DISTANCE_COLUMN      = "Distance";
public  static final String LATITUDE_COLUMN      = "Latitude";
public  static final String LONGITUDE_COLUMN     = "Longitude";
public  static final String TRIP_COLUMN          = "Trip";
```

You would then only need a single table creation statement with no logic in the `onCreate` method e.g. it could be :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createQuery =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + 
                    ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
                    NUMBER_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " +
                    DISTANCE_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, " +
                    LATITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL, " +
                    LONGITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL +
                    TRIP_COLUMN + "INTEGER" +
                    )";
    }
    db.execSQL(createQuery);
    Log.d(TAG, "Table created");
}
```

You would then not need to `getTrip` to swap tables rather you would just use `WHERE trip = respective_trip_as_int` (noting that int could be long so very likely ample numbers) to effect the same end result.